# Laravel 7 Relationships

Tags: laravel

Hi guys i’m new at using Laravel, now i’m working with Laravel 7.2.1.

I have three tables:

Table users:
id,
name,
email.

Table shops:
id,
nome_negozio.

Table user_has_shops:
shop_id,
user_id.

I want to visualize the users and the related shops in which them are registered in.

I have already set the relations in the user model:

```
public function shops()
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany(Shop::class);
    }
```

Instead in the model shop I put this:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

I don’t understand how to use them properly, I have set my user controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{


    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $data = User::latest()
                  ->leftJoin('user_has_shops', 'user_has_shops.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                  ->leftJoin('shops', 'shops.id', '=', 'user_has_shops.shop_id')
                  ->select('users.*', 'shops.nome_negozio')
                  ->get();

        return Datatables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('roles', function($row){

                    $btn = '<label class="badge bg-orange">Nessun Ruolo Assegnato</label>';                                        

                        foreach($row->getRoleNames() as $ruoli_assegnati){

                        $btn = '<label class="badge bg-teal">'.$row->getRoleNames()->implode(' , ').'</label>';


                        }

                    return $btn;
                })
                ->addColumn('shops', function($row){

                    //$btn = '<label class="badge bg-orange">Nessun Negozio Assegnato</label>'; 

                        $btn = '<label class="badge bg-teal">'.$row->nome_negozio
                        .'</label>';



                    return $btn;
                })
                ->addColumn('action', function($row){

                    $btn = '<div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                    Azioni
                                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                                </button>
                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">                                                       
                                                    <li><a href="#" class="show-modal" data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-nome="'.$row->name.'" data-email="'.$row->email.'"  data-ruoli="'.$row->getRoleNames()->implode(' , ').'">Visualizza</a></li> 
                                                    <li><a href="'.route('users.edit',$row->id).'">Modifica</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#" class="delete-modal" data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-title="'.$row->name.' - '.$row->email.'">Elimina</a></li>                                                           
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>';    


                        return $btn;
                }) 
                ->rawColumns(['roles','shops','action'])
                ->make(true);
    }

    return view('users.index');
}
```

The result is this: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/872ei.jpg)

As you can see ID 38 has two shops, but it is written in two different rows, instead of one. I want to better understand how to use this kind of relations.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should not use the left or any kind of join if you have model classes for different resources. Like in your case you have shop and user model then use the with function, not the left join and user_has_shops which work as intermediate table. or you can read from https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships link

Comment: Okay thank you very much, but I didn't understand how to use them, could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try to use laravel naming convention. Your pivot table name should be `user_shop`.

Then you can get user's shops like this:

```
$user->shops
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I changed the table name from user_has_shop to shop_user and it works with the relationship with

Comment: If the answer helped you, please vote up and mark it as the correct answer. This will help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to use the with() relation function, that gets all the rows associated in the table associated with the id you set in the model relation.

`$data = User::latest()->with('user_has_shops');`

You will also need to create another model for the user_has_shops table and add the following function:

```
public function shop()
{

    return $this->belongsTo(Shop::class);
}
```

And in your Shop model you should add :

```
public function user_shops()
{

    return $this->hasMany(UserHasShop::class);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand what you want to tell me